# Android: why does BillingClient queryPurchasesAsync() return an empty list after app reinstall?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase, billingclient

I am adding an in-app purchase feature into my Android app. I tried the following behaviour on an emulator:

- Launched the app and faked an in-app purchase (using the SKU `android.test.purchased`)
- Ensured that the in-app purchased was validated and acknowledged, when launching the app again `queryPurchasesAsync()` contains this purchase
- Deleted the app from the emulator
- Reinstalled it

When calling `queryPurchasesAsync()` again, the result list is now empty. Is that normal because I'm running the app on an emulator?

Thank you for your help

Comment: try siging in with your gmail account

Comment: Did you figured what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I purchased on (test) device and expected the purchased item to appear on the simulator (both setup with same account) but it didn't, queryPurchasesAsync() returned an empty list. I was looking around in the Play Store app for any clues but without finding anything just selected to update all apps in "Manage apps & devices". Thereafter it started working as expected.